# Plotly: Force x-axis range to remain constant when slider is used to display sequential histograms

Tags: python, slider, plotly, histogram, axis

This is relatively straightforward question but I cannot find adequate documentation to do what I want. I want the x-axis to remain constant when the slider is moved from day to day.

Here is the figure and slider for reference. Note that the x-axis ranges from appx. -3.25 to 3:

[image]

and then if I move the slider the x-axis now ranges from approx. -3 to 4.

[image]

How do I force the min and max x-axis values to remain constant?

Here is code for the example:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

total_days = 3

data = list()

for day in range(total_days):
    data.append(plotly.graph_objs.Histogram(
        x=np.random.randn(500) + day * 0.5,
        name='Day {}, control'.format(day),
        visible=day < 1
    )
    )

steps = list()
for i in range(total_days):
    step = dict(
        method='restyle',
        args=['visible', [False] * total_days * 2],
        label='Day {}'.format(i)
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    steps=steps
)]

layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the layout dictionary as follows:

```
layout = dict(sliders=sliders,
              xaxis=dict(range=[-3, 3],
                         autorange=False))
```

where:

- `range` defines the minimum and maximum value of the x-axis (in this example -3 and 3), see https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-range.
- `autorange = False` ensures that the range is kept fixed instead of being recalculated based on the input data, see https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-autorange.